# Show only the last 24hr/today inputted data from swiftui coredata

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swiftui, predicate

Im trying to show the list of the only today or last 24 hr inputted data from swiftui coredata. I didn't know the syntax or logic how to get the today data on the predicate of @FetchRequest. Can someone help, here is the code to show all the data

```
@FetchRequest(
    entity: ExpenseLog.entity(),
    sortDescriptors: [
        NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \ExpenseLog.date, ascending: true)
    ]
    //,predicate: NSPredicate...
)
private var result: FetchedResults<ExpenseLog>
```

...

```
                                ForEach(self.result)
                                {
                                    (log: ExpenseLog) in


                                    ZStack{
                                    HStack(spacing: 16) {
                                                           CategoryImageView(category: log.categoryEnum)
                                                           VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 8) {
                                                               Text(log.nameText).font(.headline)
                                                               Text(log.dateText).font(.subheadline)
                                                           }
                                                           Spacer()
                                                           Text(log.amountText).font(.headline)

                                    } .padding(.vertical, 8) .padding(.horizontal,4)
                                      }

                                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just filter your list with

```
Calendar.current.isDateInToday(yourDate)
Calendar.current.isDateInYesterday(yourDate)
```

Comment: I tried like this but it still load all of the data not the only todays data:

' @FetchRequest(
        entity: ExpenseLog.entity(),
        sortDescriptors: [
            NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \ExpenseLog.date, ascending: false)
        ]
        ,predicate: NSPredicate(value: Calendar.current.isDateInToday(Date()))
    )
    private var result: FetchedResults<ExpenseLog>'

Comment: You have to put the coredata date in the predicate, not the Date() which is now and always today!

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for filtering only the last 24hr data you can use the following one:

```swift
let startOfTheDate = Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: Date())

//...

@FetchRequest(
    entity: ExpenseLog.entity(),
    sortDescriptors: [
        NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \ExpenseLog.date, ascending: true)
    ],
    predicate: NSPredicate(format: "creationDate >= %@", startOfTheDate as CVarArg),
)
private var result: FetchedResults<ExpenseLog>
```

Don't forget that you can set the FetchRequest in the `init()`.